# ViewModel returning null into form, how do I fix this

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I can't seem to get the values I entered from the form into my action createEmployee method in the controller I think the issue is the ViewModel I may be wrong but how do I fix this. The only thing I able to recieve back when I run the project the random number I generated, and null variables, also how do I add the inputted Employee back to list **side note my Employee list is hard coded**

View.cs

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEmployee", "/Employee", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-2">First Name</div>
<div class="col-lg-10">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2">Last Name</div>
<div class="col-lg-10">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
 </div>
</div>
   <br />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2">Date of Birth</div>
<div class="col-lg-10">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2">Department</div>
<div class="col-lg-10">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee.Department, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Complete</button>
</div>

}
```

EmployeeViewModel

```
 public List<Fundi.HR.Web.Models.Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }

        public EmployeeViewModel(List<Employee> found)
        {
            this.Employees = found;
        }
```

Action EmployeeController

```
public ActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                int num = random.Next();

                Employee empObj = new Employee();
                List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

                empObj.EmployeeId = num;
                empObj.Name = emp.Name;
                empObj.Surname = emp.Surname;
                empObj.DateOfBirth = emp.DateOfBirth;
                empObj.Department = emp.Department;


                employees.Add(empObj);
                EmployeeViewModel em = new EmployeeViewModel(employees);
                return View("Index", em);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple test, I used part of your code so that the value can be accepted, you can refer to the following:
View:

```
@model WebApplication38.Models.Employee
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEmployee", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">First Name</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">Last Name</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">Date of Birth</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">Department</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Department, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Complete</button>
    </div>

}
```

[image]

Controller and result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks it works now, how do I show all the added objects into one view, because now its just showing one  the recently added only